# Direct link to hidden div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using [this](http://papermashup.com/jquery-show-hide-plugin/) plugin to toggle some hidden divs.

Each `div` has an individual id. Is there a way to show selected `div` with direct link?

For example entering domain.com/page.php#HiddenDiv2 will toggle `<div id="HiddenDiv2">`

Here is my page: http://www.snblodz.com.pl/?page_id=14

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery `ready` event as well as the JavaScript `onhashchange` event to do what you need.  Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style>
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            showHiddenDiv();
            window.onhashchange = showHiddenDiv;
        });
        function showHiddenDiv() {
            $(window.location.hash).show();            
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div-1" class="hidden">Div 1</div>
    <div id="div-2" class="hidden">Div 2</div>
    <div id="div-3" class="hidden">Div 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

To see which browsers support the `onhashchange` event, look here: http://caniuse.com/#search=onhashchange

Comment: Your method works as well as antoher one I found out on my own:

:target {display:inline;}